# D3: What are the most expensive operations?

Tags: d3.js

I was rewriting my code just now and it feels many magnitudes slower. Previously it was pretty much instant, now my animations take 4 seconds to react to mouse hovers.

I tried removing transitions and not having opacity changes but it's still really slow.

Though it is more readable. - -;

The only thing I did was split large functions into smaller more logical ones and reordered the grouping and used new selections. What could cause such a huge difference in speed? My dataset isn't large either...16kb.

edit: I also split up my monolithic huge chain.

edit2: I fudged around with my code a bit, and it seems that switching to nodeGroup.append("path") caused it to be much slower than svg.append("path"). The inelegant thing about this though is that I have to transform the drawn paths to the middle when using svg while the entire group is already transformed. Can anyone shed some insight and group.append vs svg.append?

edit3: Additionally I was using opacity:0 to hide all my path line before redrawing, which caused it to become slower and slower because these lines were never removed. Switched to remove();

Comment: post a link to what you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dlwjiang/epBab/ Here is a link.

Comment: What is your data source? The fiddle won't work without it..

Comment: Shouldn't really show the data, nothing is obvious just from the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data it is hard to work with or suggest a solution. You don't need to share private data but it helps to generate some fake data with the same structure. It's also not clear where your performance hit comes if we can't see how many dom elements you are trying to make/interact with.

As for obvious things that stand out, you are not doing things in a data driven way for drawing your segments. Any time you see a for loop it is a hint that you are not using d3's selections when you could.

You should bind listEdges to your paths and draw them from within the selection, it's ok to transform them to the center from there. also, you shouldn't do d3.select when you can do nodeGroup.select, this way you don't need to traverse the entire page when searching for your circles.

Comment: I figured it out I think. I'm redoing it over to make use of d3's selections and I believe the previous hit to performance was because I called a selection WITHIN a loop, so it was a loop inside a loop repeatedly drawing things. Thanks for the tips!